# Unable to send data from Stripe webhook to Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, stripe-payments, webhooks

I have made a Stripe webhook and I want to write data to Firebase when a Stripe purchase happens, and it isn't working although the payment always succeeds but the data is not sent to Firebase database.

In Stripe console I'm getting error as:

> Webhook error: No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload. Are you passing the raw request body you received from Stripe? https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#webhook-signing

Following is the code for my webhook:

```js
import { buffer } from "micro";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

// Secure a connection to firebase
const serviceAccount = require("../../../permession.json");
const app = !admin.apps.length
  ? admin.initializeApp({
      credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    })
  : admin.app();

// Stripe

const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

const endpointSecurit = process.env.STRIPE_SIGNING_SECRET;

const fullfillOrder = async (session) => {
  console.log("Fullfilling Order!!!");

  return app
    .firestore()
    .collection("users")
    .doc(session.metadata.email)
    .collection("orders")
    .doc(session.id)
    .set({
      amount: session.amount_total / 100,
      amount_shipping: session.total_details_amount_shipping / 100,
      images: JSON.parse(session.metadata.images),
      title: JSON.parse(session.metadata.titles),
      timestamp: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log(`SUCCESS: Order ${session.id} has been added to DB!`);
    });
};

export default async (req, res) => {
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    const requestBuffer = await buffer(req);
    const payload = requestBuffer.toString();
    const sig = req.headers["stripe-signature"];

    let event;

    // Verify (came from stripe)
    try {
      event = await stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
        payload,
        sig,
        endpointSecurit
      );
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("ERROR", e.message);
      return res.status(400).send({ message: "Webhook error: " + e.message });
    }
    if (event.type === "checkout.session.completed") {
      const session = event.data.object;

      // Fullfill the order
      return fullfillOrder(session)
        .then(() => res.status(200))
        .catch((e) =>
          res.status(400).send({ message: "WEBHOOK_ERROR: " + e.message })
        );
    }
  }
};

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
    externalResolver: true,
  },
};
```

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Can you try `const payload = req.rawBody` ?

Comment: @Dharmaraj I tried but it is giving the same error.

Comment: Can you share updated code with req.rawBody?

Comment: `const event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(req.rawBody, sig, endpointSecret);`

This should work.

Comment: Getting the actual raw body in Node is notoriously difficult, as the body is prone to modifications before you can get to it.  There's a long thread with many different possible solutions to this problem here if the solution proposed above doesn't work: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/issues/341

Answer (score 3):

**If this code has been hosted on Google Cloud Functions**, you must factor in the automatic body parsing done by the [Functions Framework](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-nodejs/blob/d894b490dda7c5fd4690cac884fd9e41a08b6668/src/server.ts#L88-L95) ([GCF docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#handling_content_types), [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#read_values_from_the_request)) prior to the request being handed over to Next.js. Because the body has been consumed already, the `bodyParser: false` instruction is pointless for the types already handled.

To help modules that depend on it, the framework attaches a `Buffer` of the request's unparsed body as the property `req.rawBody`.

If you are using a linter or TypeScript, the `req` object may be typed as a `express.Request` object which may report that this `rawBody` property doesn't exist because it is no longer a part of the Express core. You will need to merge it into the type or override the type as `express.Request | { rawBody: Buffer }` to silence them.

Plucking the relevant lines from your code:

```js
const requestBuffer = await buffer(req);
const payload = requestBuffer.toString();
const sig = req.headers["stripe-signature"];

const event = await stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
  payload,
  sig,
  endpointSecurit
);
```

should be replaced with

```js
const sig = req.headers["stripe-signature"];

const event = await stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
  req.rawBody.toString(),
  sig,
  endpointSecurit
);
```

Make sure to also check that that your environment variables have been configured correctly.

```js
const endpointSecurit = process.env.STRIPE_SIGNING_SECRET;
if (typeof endpointSecurit !== "string") {
  console.error("Unexpected value for STRIPE_SIGNING_SECRET");
  // potentially throw an error here
}
```

#### Side notes

If using the Firebase fork of Cloud Functions, you can also make use of `functions.config()` to handle your secrets instead of using environment variables.

```js
const STRIPE_SECRET = functions.config().stripe.secret;
const STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET = functions.config().stripe.webhook_secret;
```

Rather than silently ignore requests that aren't sent using `POST`, you should respond with the appropriate error:

```js
if (req.method !== "POST") {
  res.status(405).set('Allow', 'POST').send("");
  return;
}
```

Don't forget to end your requests using `.end()`, `.send()`, etc.!

```js
res.status(200).send("");
```

If you start to handle multiple webhook event types, consider switching to using an object of event handlers to help organise your code rather than have a large `if`-`else`/`switch` tree:

```js
// before the route handler
const eventHandlers = {}; // Record<string, (event, req, res) => Promise<unknown> | unknown>

eventHandlers["checkout.session.completed"] = async (event, req, res) => {
  const session = event.data.object;
  return fullfillOrder(session)
    .then(() => res.status(200))
    .catch((e) =>
      res.status(400).send({ message: "WEBHOOK_ERROR: " + e.message })
    );
}
```

```js
// in the route handler
const handler = eventHandlers[event.type];
if (!handler) {
  console.error('Ignored unexpected event type of ' + event.type);
  res.status(200).send("");
  return;
}

try {
  await Promise.resolve(handler(event, req, res))
} catch (err) {
  console.error("Unexpected error in event handler for event type of ' + event.type, err);
  res.status(500).send({ message: "Internal server error" });
}
```